# How to override toString and print out custom class type of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, overriding, tostring, println

The closest one I can found is this thread:
[How to print the value of arraylist contents in my logcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506626/how-to-print-the-value-of-arraylist-contents-in-my-logcat)

However, when I try to override the output, it gives me error: *The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (List)*

// Update:
It turns out that I dont need Arrays.toString in the System.out.println. So let me change my question into: Why do I need this Override in the Interval class anyway? I noticed that without that, I will get output like this:

```
[Interval@6d06d69c, Interval@7852e922, Interval@4e25154f, Interval@70dea4e]
```

Here is my code:

```
 public static void main (String [] args) {
     List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
     intervals.add(new Interval(1,3));
     intervals.add(new Interval(2,6));
     intervals.add(new Interval(8,10));
     intervals.add(new Interval(15,18));
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intervals));
 }
```

Here is my interval class:

```
public class Interval {
    int start;
    int end;
    Interval() {start = 0; end = 0;}
    Interval(int s, int e) {
    start = s;
    end = e;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[ " + start + ", " + end + "] ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why converting the list to array? Just print the list directly

Comment: Just print it like: System.out.println(intervals); and you will have the result as your expectation.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask a new one once the original one is answered.  If you have another question, create a new post and ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Arrays.toString(...) expects an array for input, not a list.

Comment: Ok, I am a little bit lost here. I though the reason that I did this Override toString thing is that I need to use it in the System.out.println. So, let me change my question into: Why without that Override, when I do the  System.out.println, it give me [Interval@6d06d69c, Interval@7852e922, Interval@4e25154f, Interval@70dea4e]

Comment: @Patrick `System.out.println()` implicitly calls `toString()` on the object passed in.